# Clarity about definition of Lipschitz function

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm going over the definition of a Lipschitz function and while the first part I understand; a function $F$ is Lipschitz continuous if there exists a constant $K$ such that $$|F(x)-F(y)| \leq K|x-y| \quad \textrm{for all} \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
It's the second part... Equivalently, $F$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if $F$ is absolutely continuous with $||h'||<\infty$ ... that I don't quite understand.  Can anyone help explain..?

Comment: Presumably is should read $\|F'\|_\infty < \infty$? (The essential $\sup$ norm, that is.)

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is absolutely continuous with $\|F'\| <\infty$ then $|F(x)-F(y)|=|\int_x^{y}F'(t)dt|\leq \|F'\|_{\infty} |x-y|$ so $F$ is Lipschitz. Conversely, if $|F(x)-F(y)| \leq K|x-y|$ then $F$ is absolutely continuous by definition; dividing by $x-y$ and taking limit as $y \to x$ we get $|F'(x) | \leq K$ whenever the derivative exists. Thus $\|F'\|_{\infty} \leq K $.